# Display original image using fancybox

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox, lightbox, fancybox-2

I want to display the original image in the popup using fancybox but it doesn't seems to be working. Instead it is resizing the width and height of image and container.

This is what I'm doing :

```
$("a.fancybox").fancybox({
  padding : 0,
  height : $(this).attr('data-height'),
  width : $(this).attr('data-height'),
  autoDimensions: false
});
```

My link :

```
<a href="/system/creatives/images/000/000/008/original/new_creative_form.png?1402035793" data-width="1366" data-height="768" class="fancybox">
<img src="/system/creatives/images/000/000/008/thumb/new_creative_form.png?1402035793" class="img-responsive" alt="New creative form">
</a>
```

Any idea what I should do?

Comment: Have you tried not supplying the `width` and `height` params?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Yeah still it resizes the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see the original size of an image you only need to set `fitToView` to `false` like :

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    fitToView: false
});
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/jTR2k/)**

On the other hand, if you want to manipulate specific dimensions passed through `data` attributes, then use the `beforeShow` callback like :

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    fitToView: false,
    beforeShow: function () {
        this.width = this.element.data("width");
        this.height = this.element.data("height");
    }
});
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Y9rYb/)**

**Notice** we still nedd `fitToView: false`.

**IMPORTANT** :

This is for fancyBox v2.1.5, make sure you download the [latest master](https://github.com/fancyapps/fancyBox/archive/master.zip) to be updated.

Comment: To use fancyBox v2.1.5 .. we need to purchase it for commercial purpose. Right?

Comment: @SachinPrasad : all fancyBox v2.x need a license for commercial websites but you can use it free for personal or non-profit websites. Learn more http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#license